# How to work with queries from multiple databases

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 2 queries from 2 different databases.I need to create a report with those 2 queries. Please suggest.

Comment: How do you want to show the data? You have two options, first you create your report with the first query, than you create a subreport with the second query. If you want all the data on one report I think you should create a view on the database and join the data

Comment: Hi Raphael I need to merge both the queries

Comment: Can you craete a view on your database?

Comment: how about posting the queries?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about your databases, the way you combine multiple databases is by using the UNION command. An example:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.Table1
```

You can also create a view that by adding `CREATE VIEW CombinedTable1 AS` as the first line.
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) is a good introduction on how to use UNION.

Hope that helps,

Chris